# Dynamic CSS border depends on number of contents

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what is this called, and already searched it on google but doesnt found what I want,

but here is what I want to looks like

[image]

Can someone help me to achieve this? or maybe what is this called?

and if there are only 1 content, then no border at all

and, I'm using `div` not `table` tag

Comment: Flex is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

It's taken from codepen but modified as per your requirements.

page.html

```
    <table class="table">

  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table" style="margin-top:30px;">

  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table" style="margin-top:30px;">

  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table" style="margin-top:30px;">

  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
      <td class="cell"><span>Cool</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

page.css

```
.cell {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
.cell span{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}

.table-head > .row {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

See the screenshot

http://prnt.sc/pdptlg

Answer (score 1):

try checking out this example, it shows a table with inner borders only, without the outer borders.

```css
.cell {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}

.table-head > .row {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Taken from https://codepen.io/sirinity/pen/dDsLx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but how to make it like this using div? and pure CSS?

Comment: you can try setting `display: table; display: table-cell; ` etc. to your elements

Answer (score 1):

One way only using pure css. Hope this help

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 150px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50px;   
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0 solid;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;   
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #030;
}

.wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.wrapper:nth-of-type(odd), .wrapper:nth-of-type(even) { 
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.wrapper:last-child, .wrapper:nth-last-of-type(-n+2):not(:nth-child(even)) {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">1</div></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">2</div></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">3</div></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">4</div></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">5</div></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">6</div></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><div class="content">7</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css pseudo-classes

More info here: [Css pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Yout HTML dosnt change:

```
 <table class="table">      
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
      <td class="cell">Cool</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in css:

```
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}

.cell {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.row:nth-of-type(1n+1) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid pink; 
}

.cell:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
  border-right: 2px solid pink;  
}
```

Explanation:

Just skip first row to set top border:

```
.row:nth-of-type(1n+1) {
      border-bottom: 2px solid pink; 
}
```

and then, set border only to odd cells:

```
.cell:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
      border-right: 2px solid pink;  
}
```

[Code here](https://codepen.io/ChemaAlfonso/pen/XWrvRLJ)

Hope it helps you.

Edit: Sorry but i didnt notice that you are not using table tags, Hải Bùi response is the way for that, my css only works properly with tables.